# Embed a UserVoice widget in an add-in in Excel for Windows

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, uservoice

(* I clean up the initial thread *)

I want to add the UserVoice widget to one Excel add-in. I have made the following example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="contact_us">Contact us</div>
  </body>
  <script>
    // Include the UserVoice JavaScript SDK (only needed once on a page)
    UserVoice=window.UserVoice||[];(function(){var uv=document.createElement('script');uv.type='text/javascript';uv.async=true;uv.src='//widget.uservoice.com/KIXLyRfZDu6MdnaaVtnlSw.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv,s)})();

    UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#contact_us', {}]);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works well under [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/becoloxoge/1/edit?html,output) and `Excel Online`, clicking on `Contact us` shows the message window. However, under `Excel 2016 for Windows`, after several seconds of loading (as expected), clicking `Contact us` does not open such a window.

[image]

I don't know if there is something special we need to set up in `Home.html` or the manifest file of the add-in, or the setting of Excel for Windows. I am also trying to change the position where the window is supposed to pop up (but still not yet works)... Could anyone help?

**Edit 1**
I test the code of Michael Saunders, it works under Excel Online, but still does not work in Excel for Windows. The follows is a screenshot. Note that, after clicking on `Contact us`, the triangle symbol (in red) appeared (in my initial example, it has the same phenomena. And if we just click on the blank area of the task pane, it has the same phenomena too.)

Maybe the box is already shown, but not in an area of the task pane that we can see?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete working page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UserVoice test</title>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contact_us">Contact us</div>
</body>
<script>
    UserVoice=window.UserVoice||[];(function(){var uv=document.createElement('script');uv.type='text/javascript';uv.async=true;uv.src='//widget.uservoice.com/KIXLyRfZDu6MdnaaVtnlSw.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv,s)})();
    UserVoice.push(['set', {
        width:'300px',
        post_suggestion_enabled:true
    }]);
    UserVoice.push(['identify', {}]);
    UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#contact_us', { mode: 'contact',menu_enabled:true, }]);
</script>
</html>
```

Some things I changed include:

- Changed the `#contact_us` element to be a div instead of a link.
- Removed your extra  tag
- Added the optional parameters in the `addTrigger` call
- Added `identify` and `set` statements

Also, make sure your environment is in a good state:

- Clear your browser cache to ensure that old code isn't present during debugging: open Internet Explorer (not Edge) and select Safety > Delete Browsing History > Select all boxes > Delete > close all IE windows and all Office windows.
- Host the code online

Comment: It does not work... Actually, I realise that the window is due to `href="mailto:questions@uservoice.com"`. Clicking on `Contact us` leads to sending an email... So what should I put as the value of `href`? I tried almost all the ways [here](https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/widgets/methods/), but none of them works in an add-in...

Comment: Ah, changed my answer since I didn't notice you were using a link. That's the problem.

Comment: I put exactly [this code](http://jsbin.com/cojabawupu/2/edit?html,output) to my Home.html. The JSBin works, whereas this codes does not work in an add-in: clicking on `Contact us` does not have any reaction...

Comment: Ok, I've edited my response to include my entire working sample with all the fixes

Comment: I tested your your response, it still does not work... really odd, please see the update in the OP...

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache - instructions added

Comment: Are you hosting the code locally or on the internet?

Comment: I've hosted this exact page at https://michael-saunders.com/testing/uv.html. Point your manifest there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118473/discussion-between-michael-saunders-and-softtimur).

Comment: I tried to host the code on the internet, it finally works... did not know there may be a difference between locally and on the internet... Thank you very much...

Comment: No problem. Must be some weird check that Uservoice is doing for some reason

Answer (score 1):

In terms of loading-speed, could you load the UserVoice dynamically, i.e., using [jQuery.getScript(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

For #2, what were you expecting?

Comment: For getString, please see my update... I didn't use the `url` argument, is it correct (the test is fine)?